# How to use filters inside directives in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I want to use filters in `v-text`, like this:

```
..
<tr v-for="item in data.data">
  <td v-text="item.XX | myFilter"></td>
</tr>
```

but `myFilter` does not work. I do not want to use `{{item.XX | myFilter}}`.

Answer (score 5):

As per [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters):

> Vue 2.x filters can only be used inside mustache bindings. To achieve the same behavior inside directive bindings, you should use [Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead.

So you cannot achieve what you are trying there. Instead, `item` would need a property which returns the transformed value directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with computed property + method.
Instead of:

```
<td v-text="item.XX | myFilter"></td>
```

use:

```
<td v-text="myFilter(item.xx)"></td>
```

and in your script part of component add:

```
methods: {
  myFilter(item) {
    // your filter logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<tr v-for="item in data.data">
  <td :text-content.prop="item.XX | myFilter"></td>
</tr>
```